# GWT Table with collapsible rows

Tags: gwt, rows

Anyone know an open source component for a GWT Table with collapsible rows?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with "pure" GWT, check out the [TreeTable](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/TreeTable) ([demo](http://google-web-toolkit-incubator.googlecode.com/svn/branches/dflorey/tableAddons/demo/TreeTableDemo/TreeTableDemo.html)) from the GWT Incubator project - it seems exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [SmartGWT](http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/) is open source.

It contains a GridList widget, which supports collapsible rows. See the showcase [here](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_memo_rows). This is of course not a table, as you asked for, but it comes quite close :)